# Unable to access flash on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, flash, adobe-flash

I know that there are a few hoops to jump through to use flash on chrome, but after having reformatted my HDD today, I am unable to get flash working on chrome.

I have the latest chrome browser (Version 69.0.3497.100), The latest flash is installed (31.0.0.108).

When I load a page with flash, I allow flash to run on that site, through the security lock icon near the address bar. I refresh (I have restarted my PC also). The flash appears to do an initial load, but not progress further.
One example leaves me with a black rectangle, but right clicking within it gives me the flash context menu but nothing loads (I have confirmed that it works in firefox). The Version information box found on this page: https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/about/?sdid=9WGN463Z&mv=other loads, but doesn't actually show the version where it should or the button doesn't respond etc. Screenshot shows this:

[image]

How do I allow flash to actually fully run on Chrome? What step have I missed?

Comment: Try this: Disable `chrome://flags/#enable-ephemeral-flash-permission`. Expect future Chrome updates to make it even harder to run Flash.

Comment: Thats good to know and will be useful, however my issue, which I just managed to resolve, was kind of my bad. I had Ghostery plugin installed. I originally set it up to block a small number of things, nothing that should affect flash. However, it had decided it wanted to block nearly everything, and ghostery was doing the additional blocking.